# Is there any problem with this camera not having a lens cover?

Tags: lens-design, fujifilm

I am considering buying the Fujifilm FinePix XP140, shown here: https://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/xp/finepix_xp140/.

I notice that most other cameras either have some form of lid that can be removed or have a cover that closes automatically when the camera is powered off.

When I tested the camera in the store, I noticed I was able to power on and take a picture must faster than the other point-and-shoots, which I suspect is because it doesn't use any energy to open.

Does this lack of a cover leave the camera vulnerable to all kinds of damage, dust, etc. ruining the lens, including when storing it in a case?

Comment: What do you do about the lack of cover for your phone camera?

Answer (score 7):

A lens cap or cover is hardly necessary. Minor scratches won't really affect your image quality (LensRentals [1](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches/) & [2](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/08/the-apocalypse-of-lens-dust/)).

What a lens cap *does* do is protect the lens in transit so that you can instantly take a shot - no accidental finger prints or dirt smudged while en route. That being said, the lens appears to be recessed, making the accidental finger print an infrequent occurrence. As for dust, water prints, etc., this is a camera designed to go places - you don't buy it for stellar image quality and features; you buy it to take it where you wouldn't want to take a DSLR.

It's going to get wet, be in salt water, get dusty and probably dropped a few times. Cleaning off the lens before you go to shoot will become second nature for this kind of camera *anyway*. So, the fact that it doesn't have a lens cap is no real loss.

Comment: It looks like the kind of camera you just run under the tap if it's looking a bit grungy ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin **exactly**. Funny story - I was photographing a dance competition on a cruise ship back when the Olympus Tough first came out. My partner and I were walking past the ship's camera shop with all of our gear and the salesmen got our attention then threw the camera toward the ground. I think my heart stopped as I tried to catch it. Of course the camera was fine...that instinct though

Comment: There are so many problems with that PetaPixel article that it is embarrassing to read. Roger Cicala does much better in [this lensrentals blog entry.](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches/) about front element scratches and [this one](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/08/the-apocalypse-of-lens-dust/) about dust and lenses.

Comment: @MichaelC Roger is definitely more scientific about it. Updated to reference his links. Peta has him beat on SEO for this one, apparently ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lens cover in the backup camera of my car. The lens is in very, very dirty conditions in the rear of the car.

I am aware that some cars have a backup camera that is hidden until one selects the reverse gear. My car doesn't.

I carry a microfiber cloth in my car, to wipe the backup camera when the image quality becomes unacceptable. Even though the sand on the lens is very abrasive, I have never managed to destroy the image quality when wiping away the abrasive sand.

It takes a LOT of dirt to reach the level where I need to wipe the lens. I'm pretty sure you don't need to carry a cloth with this camera in the question.

Seriously, you have no issue with the lens in this camera. Especially if you store the camera in a case when carrying it, you will have no issues.

I don't have a lens cover in my phone camera, either. I have never wiped the phone camera lens. It takes acceptable pictures even today.